# PHP Mysql Sum children and acumulate with parents tree

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, sum

I have a database table with the name `dt_account` data and the structure is more or less like this :

[image]

and a transaction table with the name `dt_jurnaltransaksi` and a structure like this :

[image]

This is the result of querying the table above with the child parent tree, and this is what happens in my code:

[image]

and this is the result that should be and what I want like this, so the `total` data is also in the parent account

[image]

this is the php file that I use

```
<?php
#MUTASI DEBIT KREDIT
$sql_labarg = "SELECT  
        T1.uq_account,
        T1.kd_parent,  
        T1.nama_akun,   
        T1.main, 
        SUM(T2.debit) AS debit, 
        SUM(T2.kredit) AS kredit 
    FROM dt_account AS T1
    LEFT JOIN dt_jurnaltransaksi AS T2 
        ON T2.uq_account = T1.uq_account 
    GROUP BY T1.uq_account 
    ORDER BY T1.id_sort ASC, T1.kd_account 
";  ?>

<div class="mt-4 p-6 shadow-[0_2px_20px_-5px_rgba(0,0,0,0.1)] rounded bg-white">  
    <div class="w-full max-lg:px-3 max-lg:mt-8"> 
        <div class="p-0 m-0"> <?php  
            $data = array();
            $query  = mysqli_query($db, $sql_labarg);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $sb_countv = $db->query("SELECT 
                        SUM(T2.kredit) - SUM(T2.debit) AS nominal_hr 
                    FROM dt_account AS T1  
                    LEFT JOIN dt_jurnaltransaksi AS T2 
                        ON T2.uq_account = T1.uq_account  
                    WHERE T1.kd_parent = '{$row['uq_account']}' 
                ")->fetch_assoc(); 
                
                $tmp[$row['uq_account']]['uq_account']  = $row['uq_account'];
                $tmp[$row['uq_account']]['kd_parent']   = $row['kd_parent']; 
                $tmp[$row['uq_account']]['nama_akun']   = $row['nama_akun'];
                $tmp[$row['uq_account']]['main']        = $row['main'];  
                
                #AKUN
                $tmp[$row['uq_account']]['debit']   = $row['debit'];
                $tmp[$row['uq_account']]['kredit']  = $row['kredit']; 

                $tmp[$row['uq_account']]['nominal_hr']  = $sb_countv['nominal_hr']; 

                if ($row['kd_parent'] == '0') {
                    $data[$row['uq_account']]  = &$tmp[$row['uq_account']];
                } else { 
                    $tmp[$row['kd_parent']]['child'][$row['uq_account']] = &$tmp[$row['uq_account']];
                }
            }    

            function build_laba($array, $child = false) {   
                $html = '<table class="table w-[calc(100%+1px)] left-[-1px]">';
                foreach ($array as $arr) { 
                    $nominal    = $arr['pos_saldo'] == 'debit' ? 
                                  $arr['kredit'] - $arr['debit'] : 
                                  $arr['debit'] - $arr['kredit'];
                    $nomittl    = $arr['nominal_hr'];
                    $nominal    = number_format($nominal, 0, '.', '.'); 

                    if($arr['main'] == 0){
                        $html .= '
                        <tr class="border-0 border-l">
                            <td class="p-0 pl-4"> 
                                <div class="py-1 my-1"> 
                                    <div class="flex flex-nowrap space-x-2 px-2"> 
                                        <div class="flex-1"> 
                                            <i class="fa-regular fa-folder-closed"></i>
                                            <span class="font-semibold text-sm">
                                              '.$arr['nama_akun'].'
                                            </span>
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>'; 

                                if (key_exists('child', $arr)) { 
                                    $html .= build_laba($arr['child'], true);
                                } 
                                
                                $html .= ' 
                            </td>
                        </tr>'; 
                    } else{
                        $html .= '
                        <tr class="border-0 '.$brdr.'"> 
                            <td class="p-0 '.$hder.'"> 
                                <div class="py-1 hover:!bg-gray-100 text-gray-600"> 
                                    <div class="flex flex-nowrap space-x-2 px-2"> 
                                        <div class="flex-1"> 
                                            <i class="fa-regular fa-folder"></i>
                                            <span class="text-sm">'.$arr['nama_akun'].'</span>
                                        </div> 
                                        
                                        <div class="flex-0">'.$nominal.'</div> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </td> 
                        </tr> ';
                    } 

                    #TOTAL AKUN
                    if($arr['main'] == 0){
                        $html .= '
                        <tr class="border-0 '.$brdr.'">
                            <td class="p-0 '.$hder.'"> 
                                <div class="py-1 my-1 '.$hdbg.'"> 
                                    <div class="flex flex-nowrap space-x-2 px-2"> 
                                        <div class="flex-1"> 
                                            <i class="fa-regular fa-folder-closed"></i>
                                            <span class="font-semibold text-sm">
                                              Total '.$arr['nama_akun'].'
                                            </span>
                                        </div> 

                                        <div class="flex-0">
                                          '.number_format($nomittl, 0, '.', '.').'
                                         </div> 
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>'; 
                    } 
                } 

                $html .= '</table>';
                return $html;
            }

            echo build_laba($data); 
        ?>   
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: And what's your question about this code? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your code that should correctly calculate the sum of the child nodes and add it to the parent node's total.

```
function calculateTotal(&$array) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($array as &$arr) {
        if (isset($arr['child'])) {
            $arr['nominal_hr'] += calculateTotal($arr['child']);
        }
        $total += $arr['nominal_hr'];
    }
    return $total;
}

// Call the function on your data array
calculateTotal($data);

// Now you can build your table as before
echo build_laba($data);
```